# Single shower only valve indentification

Tags: shower

My single shower valve is leaking and I can't identify the brand. There is no stamping on the plate other than C and H. No stamping on valve body. I have not taken it apart due to being a rental and if I cant put it back together with minimal leaking it would not be a good thing.

There is a design on the handle similar to Moen but according to Home depot it is not Moen but probably Valley? I bought a Danco Valley VA-1 cartridge and repair kit so hopefully that will work. Anyone out there has experienced this type of valve? Any assistance much appreciated.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are there any markings under the escutcheon plate?

Comment: The pics appear now. Looks like a Delta to me.

Comment: No markings. The house was built in 1970 if that helps. Thx

Comment: The valve fully opens vertically less than half way and 45 degrees to each side for temperature

Comment: David Any suggestions for a Delta cartridge

Comment: Call Delta customer service. Most major faucet manufacturers can identify their products from a picture. They can also supply the correct parts. My guess is either Delta or Kohler.

Comment: Thank you for your assistance

Answer (score 1):

Hey wanted to get back incase this shower valve question arises again. Called Kohler, delta and Moen, sent pics and all said it was not theirs. Only option was to remove and verify. It is a Valley valve made by US BRASS back in the old days. I used the VA-1 valley cartridge from Danco and 80868 spring and oring kit.[old VA1 valve[image: VA1 side angle]